# Get Total Hours From Excel TEXT Function

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have a column in my worksheet that is a subtraction of "End Time" and "Start Time", giving me the total number of hours:minutes:Seconds during. Sample Input:

```
Start Time: 15/04/2019  1:38:00 PM
End Time  : 18/04/2019  3:00:00 PM
```

Basic subtraction gives me the right value i.e.

```
73:22:00
```

However for other dependent calculations/graphs, I need to convert the output using **TEXT** as shown below:

```
TEXT([End Time]-[Start Time],"h:mm:ss")
```

Understandably, this does not provide me the desired output, the output is as follows:

```
1:22:00
```

If I add **d** to the function parameter:

```
TEXT([End Time]-[Start Time],"d h:mm:ss")
```

it gives me:

```
3 1:22:00
```

I want to get total hours, not the number of days. Basically:

```
73:22:00
```

Using:

```
TEXT([End Time]-[Start Time],<parameters>
```

Would greatly appreciate if someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[hh]` to display hours greater than 24.

```
=TEXT([End Time]-[Start Time],"[hh]:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for swift response, this fixed the issue I was facing and caters to my requirement.